# Есть ли в Windows аналог /dev/null?

Tags: windows, dev-null

[Аналог вопроса на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313111/is-there-a-dev-null-on-windows)

Есть ли в Windows аналог `/dev/null`?

Есть проблемы с перенаправлением в "никуда" в Windows.

Например, мне нужно убрать вывод какой-нибудь программы.

В Linux я сделал бы так:

```sh
cat test.txt > /dev/null
```

Но как это сделать в Windows?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145280/discussion-on-question-by-nchistov----windows--dev-null); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Windows cmd надо делать так:

```sh
type test.txt > nul
```

В PowerShell это делается так:

```sh
type test.txt > $null
```

Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://ss64.com/nt/nul.html).

Comment: Раньше была рекомендация убирать пробел после стрелки.

Comment: @Qwertiy, почему нужно убирать пробел после стрелки?

Comment: @maestro, типа может не сработать... Но это была очень древняя рекомендация, не уверен про её актуальность.

Comment: @Qwertiy AFAIK рекомендация была исключительно для читаемости в batch файлах. Раздельно — файл, слитно — в молоко.